# sharepoint 2010 change system account

Tags: user-accounts

How can I get my login account to not show as `[System Account]`?

I've setup up SharePoint locally on my system as standalone environment, using my windows credentials [Domain\Username] to set it up.

Everything is working perfectly fine except one thing which is as soon as I any access any site / CA, I am logging in as SharePoint\System [System Account].

But I want it to show as my local account and not the system account.

- I have already checked that [SharePoint Central Administration v4] application pool is running on my local account[domain\username].
- [Web Application -80] app pool is running on Network Service account & [SecurityTokenServiceApplication] app pool is running on LocalSystem.
- Also, within central admin's farm administration section, I have removed my Local account [domain\username].

*I have read a lot of technet and msdn articles on it & it states that this could be happening because of various reasons.*

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?  You should break up your paragraph some more because it is difficult to read.

Comment: Setup up SharePoint locally on my system as standalone environment. Used my windows credentials [Domain\Username] to set it up. Everything is working perfectly fine except one thing which is as soon as I any access any site / CA, I am logging in as SharePoint\System [System Account]. **Which is the issue.**  I dont know how to seperate my account so that it cannot appear as system account

Comment: I cleaned up your question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System Account is the one you specified in Sharepoint Central Administration as the Farm Administrator.  It will always show as `[System Account]`.

I created for myself a separate user account with full rights and use that account instead.

Here are some similar questions with answers (here on SSE):

- [Why are some users appearing as system account?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53222/why-are-some-users-appearing-as-system-account)
- [Can only see 'System Account' as the current user instead of domain account](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/can-only-see-system-account-as-the-current-user-instead-of-domain-account)
- [Changing System Account of Central Admin on MOSS 2007](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43284/changing-system-account-of-central-admin-on-moss-2007)

Answer (score 0):

The above is true in a complete farm setup! In my case, I have sharepoint 2010 setup on my local win 7 machine. Which dont allow provisioning user profile services also no access to AD and above that it uses SQL Express. because of this setup whenever I provisioned a new web application using my domain/windows username, it reflects as SYSTEM ACCOUNT. Thou  app pool acct was Network Service the farm admin account was using my username. Therefore the avoid this, i have re-provisioned the web app using Network Service acct. Which resolved my issue. TX.